# How to change bluetooth audio sampling rate under Big Sur

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I am using Big Sur 11.7.1, and there is a loud artifact when playing music through the bluetooth audio device, when tracks change.

I see in Audio MIDI Setup that the sampling rate is 48000 Hz, rather than 44.1 kHz.  I recall that under a previous version, changing that to 44.1 kHz may have fixed this.

But "Format" is not adjustable for Bluetooth audio in this tool.  How does one modify that under Big Sur?  I've searched for this online, and haven't found an answer.

If the Bluetooth tool under Xcode would do it, how to I obtain that for Big Sur?  The vanilla one is not compatible, it seems.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot change the sampling rate in Audio MIDI Setup.app? Have you tried creating a "Multi-output device" that contains just the BT audio device?

Comment: I contemplated that, but have not ever created new audio devices.  Is "Audio MIDI Setup.app" the same thing as the Audio MIDI Setup I found under Utilities?

Comment: Yes, it's the same app. Try it.